# How to know the internet connection details using Visual C++ Win32 API

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I have to create a log file for all internet connections made by PC. It should have details of the username, time of connection, etc. I do know about the `InternetGetConnectedState()` function which returns the `boolean` value. Know how do I get the other details. Can some one help me out thanks in advance. I am using Win32 API and Visual c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Network List Manager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370769%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get list of networks using `IEnumNetworks`. Then use [INetwork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370750%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface to get network information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RasEnumConnections` to enumerate the current connections. You can then call `RasGetLinkStatistics` to get information about each link (connection speed, amount of data sent and/or received, time connected, etc.) If you want to know the address assigned to the client on a PPP connection, you have to retrieve that separately with `RasGetProjectionInfo`. If you want information about the connection (e.g. the name of the modem) you can retrieve that with `RasGetConnectStatus`.